# HTML5 Canvas fill area under the curve

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to draw graph and fill area under it. Please check screenshot:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Does anyone know to fill this figure with transparent right border? Thank you

Code is

```
      context.beginPath()
      ... 
      context.lineTo(lastX, lastY);
     // context.moveTo(lastX, dimensions.height);  /* this doesnt work*/
      context.lineTo(lastX, dimensions.height);    /* so I have to jump from (lastX,lastY) to (lastX,dimensions.height) without drawing line. Idk how to do it without breaking fillpath */

      context.lineTo(firstX, dimensions.height);
      context.fillStyle = 'rgb(12,34,56)';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke(); /* this makes border wide */
      ...
      context.closePath()
```

Comment: could you show us your code so far and what you have done. It would help us to help you

Comment: Thanks for comment. Just added my code, check it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward approach would be to draw the green area and the blue line separately. First, do exactly what you have above, but without the `context.stroke();`, and then repeat for the line across the top, using `stroke()` but not `fill()`.

Comment: Thanks, had the same solution. Strange that canvas doesnt support moveTo in the path